# surface has two geodesic with fixed angle must be a developing surface

Tags: geometry, surfaces

It seems easy to show by Gauss-Bonnet theorem that a surface which has two families of geodesics with fixed angle $\theta$ must be locally flat, i.e. its Gauss curvature $K=0$. But to show it is in fact a developing surface, we must to show it is also a ruled surface, which, on the other hand, seems nonsense for me.

My quesion is that is there any counter-example?

Comment: What does "two families of geodesics with fixed angle $\theta$" mean?

Comment: I mean, as $u$-curve and $v-curve$ are two families of curves, there exists two families of curves, each of which are consist of geodesics, what's more every two pair of curves comes from the two families respectively forms a constant angle $\theta$.

Comment: And are your surfaces assumed to be contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$? If not, I don't know what you mean by "ruled surface".

Comment: Yes, it is a regular surface contained in $R^3$!